# Pass variable value on a third page while click on link between first and second pages

Tags: php, variables

Problem: i need to pass variable value to variable on page 03.php through click on link located on page 01.php and leading to page 02.php. Is it possible? And if it is - how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store this value in session - use `$_SESSION` array:

In `01.php`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = $value;
```

In `03.php`:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['variable'];
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok, but i don't want to view the result, i need pass the result to another variable. Got any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some syntax, i'm total newbie)

Comment: `$value = $_SESSION['variable'];`

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, mark the tick below answer's score (in the top left).